# Access keeps asking to enter parameter value

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007

I have the following query in Access:

```
SELECT Death.AccountNumber, Count(*) AS NumberOfRecords
FROM Death
GROUP BY Death.AccountNumber
HAVING (((Count(*))>1));
```

The field AccountNumber has previously been [Acc Number] but this has been updated in both the source Excel spreadsheet to which the Access table is linked and the SQL code in the query.

Nevertheless, every time I run the query Access still prompts me to "Enter Parameter Value" with the description: "Death: duplicate account numbers.Acc Number".

How do I get Access to stop displaying this prompt?

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't have anything in it about  "Death: duplicate account numbers.Acc Number", so there must be some code elsewhere looking for that parameter. As long as its in the code somewhere, you will get the prompt.

**NOTE: Make a copy before making doing the below.**

Here is a way to find the rouge code:

---

1. Open the VBA window, (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>).
2. Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Replace** window.
3. Type `Acc Number` in the "find what" window.
4. Type `AccountNumber` in the "replace with" window.
5. Choose `Current Project`
6. Use the "Find Next" button to find any missed references.
7. If you find a reference needing changed, click "replace".
8. After changing all found references debug the code, run it to see if it works as you desire.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem in a local table, where Access was not finding the field name in another query and kept asking for the parameter value.

I discovered that I hadn't saved the queries after renaming the field names, and once I saved them it worked as expected.